# CSS3: Animate opacity and scale by applying class, and animate back by removing class

Tags: css, animation

I have been experimenting and trying but have not been able to achieve the following. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I haven't hit it yet.

Let's say I want to animate an element (eg. div) when I apply a class (eg. active). And I want to reverse the animation when I remove the class (or toggle with another).

The properties I would like animate are scale (transform) and opacity.

Also, when entering the page, the element will not have any class, and should snap to its state, and not animate. It should only animate when explicitely adding or removing the class.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bertvan/9r98w/

HTML:

```
<div id="the-div"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="trigger();">Trigger</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#the-div").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#the-div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("http://placeimg.com/200/200/any");
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#the-div.active{
    /* animate scale & opacity */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: it is a very basic situation, I figured I don't need to include CSS?

Comment: Basic for you, but for future visitors you need to provide code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9r98w/1/

Comment: Thanks, but won't this animate other stuff as well, when I add other classes? I only want to animate the CSS of the "active" class.

Comment: You can set transition-property to animate only width, height, opacity etc. I've set it in this example to "all".

Comment: Rephrasing that: Thanks, but this will probably animate all props from all classes I add to the DIV? I only want to animate the CSS of the "active" class. Other property changes should still "snap". So let's say I have a "super-active" class, with opacity 0.2, and I don't want that to animate when applying the class... Would that work in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `transition` property on the div selector:

<kbd>[running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9r98w/2/)</kbd>

code added:

```
#the-div{
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: +1 because I did not know `http://placeimg.com/*/*/any` and it is AMAZING for demos.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a code to toggle class for changing size of a div with the transition-animation.

1. The HTML:

   - input-button with id="setRemoveClassBtn"
   - a div-tag with id="div1"
2. You will need a CSS-class-definition (notice that this is with the moz-prefix made to work in Firefox):

   ```
   div{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background-color: rgb(250, 250, 150);
   -moz-transition: width 5s, height 5s;
   }

   div.bigSizeDivs{
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   }
   ```
3. You will have to use javascript/jQuery to add/remove class. Here is an example with jQuery

   ```
   $("#setRemoveClassBtn").click(function(){
       $("#div1").toggleClass("bigSizeDivs");
   });
   ```